# reactjs antd Autocomplete: Invalid values for props `$$typeof`, `type`

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to write a searchbar in reactjs and antd autocomplete but I have this error:

```
Invalid values for props `$$typeof`, `type` on div tag
```

here is the code of my home page:

```
const Home = () => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
    const { data, loading } = useQuery(query, {
        skip: searchQuery.length < MIN_QUERY_LENGTH,
        variables: { searchTitle: searchQuery }
    });

    const handleChange = useCallback(
        _.throttle(searchQuery => {
            setSearchQuery(searchQuery)
        }, THROTTLE_TIME), [setSearchQuery]);
    
    const options = !loading && data && data.mangas && data.mangas.map(manga => {
        return (
            <Option key={manga.id} value={manga.title} >
                {manga.title}
            </Option>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div className="main-search-container">
            <Search
                options={options}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    );
};
```

and here the code of my searchbar:

```
const Search = ({ options, onChange }) => (
  <div className= "certain-categorie-search-wrapper"
      style={{ width: 500}}>
      <AutoComplete
        className="certain-categorie-search"
        dropdownClassName="certain-category-search-dropdown"
        dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
        dropdownStyle={{ width: 300}}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        options={options}
        onChange={onChange} 
        placeholder="Search Mangas"
      >
        <Input
          suffix={
            <SearchOutlined />
          }  />

    </AutoComplete>

  </div>
  
);
```

you can find my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-curie-44vb3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

from what I see, I can't use manga.title in the Option field but I don't understand how to fix it. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you show the `<Option />` code? Also, can you explain why you `can't use manga.title`? The best approach is to create a codesandbox (You can form [mine](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mendeleev-pktnh) that reproduces the issue. You probably can't fetch the data, so just replace it with hardcoded array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, here is the fork i made from your codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-curie-44vb3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I reproduced the exact problem that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click to see the correct way to use](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-williamson-m833t?file=/src/App.js)

The option element that you are using is wrong. It should come from the Autocomplete element itself:

```
const { Option } = AutoComplete;
```

Also if you would like to use the Option the result of the map should be the **CHILD** of the Autocomplete.

```
const options = mangas.map((manga) => {
  return (
    <Option key={manga.id} value={manga.title}>
      {manga.title}
    </Option>
  );
});

const Search = ({ options, onChange }) => (
  <div className="certain-categorie-search-wrapper" style={{ width: 500 }}>
    <AutoComplete
      className="certain-categorie-search"
      dropdownClassName="certain-category-search-dropdown"
      dropdownMatchSelectWidth={300}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      onSearch={onChange}
      placeholder="Search Mangas"
    >
      {options}
    </AutoComplete>
  </div>
);
```

Check the API here to learn more [Autocomplete API](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/)